# iTunes — how to install VoiceOver Kit manually?

Tags: itunes, windows, voiceover

I'm using iTunes 12.12.3.5 on Windows 11 and if I connect my iPod Shuffle (4th gen. from 2011, software version 1.0.1) and click on "Enable VoiceOver" and "Apply" nothing happens (iTunes would usually start downloading the VoiceOver Kit in this case).

Is there any way to download and install the VoiceOver Kit "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy iPodVoiceOver.dll from C:\Program Files\iPod\bin to C:\Program Files\iTunes and the problem is fixed!

Found the solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252931926 (the *iPodVoiceOver.dll* was missing).